# Replace DIVs without attributes with P

Tags: php, html, replace, preg-replace

I have a string which contains html.

Example:

```
$content="<div>content<div style=''>some<div>another</div></div> <div>test</div> </div>";
```

I want to replace all `div`s without attributes, to paragraphs.

I tried

```
$content = preg_replace( '/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/', '<p>$1</p>', $content);
```

but it returns:

```
<p>content<div style=''>some<div>another</p></div> <p>test</p> </div>
```

which is not what I want. I want to replace all `div` without attributes to `p`.

What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: `'/<div>([^<]*)<\/div>/'`

Comment: maybe, you better to use DomDocument to parce html

Comment: I would like to use `preg_replace`. Thank you @splash58

Comment: Doing this with regex is like using a steak knife to perform surgery. You can do it, but it's not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = str_replace("<div>","<p>",$content);
$content = str_replace("</div>","</p>",$content);
echo $content
```

Comment: It is not correct. It will replace all divs with `p` tags. I want to be able to replace only divs which don't have attributes. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: $content = str_replace("<div>","<p>",$content);
$content = str_replace("</div>","</p>",$content);
echo $content

Comment: Thank you for your response!! It is not correct. All divs without attributes will remain not ended. It will transform `<div style="">some</div>` to `<div style="">some</p>`